# How can I remove an option from the default compile command template for a specific compiler?

Tags: cmake, tricore

Any normal `gcc` compatible compiler specifies the source file with `-c` option ([compile but not link](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#index-c)). I have to deal with "Tasking" compiler which doesn't like this option. `-c` option for this TASKING compiler [indicates C standard](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2015076.pdf) (page 280) indicates the C standard.
I've used the common way to specify the compiler using the toolchain file:

```
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "${AURIX_SDK_ROOT}/bin/ctc" CACHE INTERNAL "")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "${AURIX_SDK_ROOT}/bin/cptc" CACHE INTERNAL "")

foreach (_prefix C CXX)
    # set(CMAKE_${_prefix}_COMPILER "${AURIX_SDK_ROOT}/bin/cctc")
    # This is used only if we skip auto compiler identification
    set(CMAKE_${_prefix}_COMPILER_ID "Tasking")
    set(CMAKE_${_prefix}_COMPILER_VERSION "6.3r1")

    # Skip compiler ID identification: use "Tasking"
    set(CMAKE_${_prefix}_COMPILER_ID_RUN TRUE CACHE INTERNAL "")
    set(CMAKE_${_prefix}_COMPILER_FORCED TRUE CACHE INTERNAL "")

    SET(CMAKE_${_prefix}_COMPILER_WORKS TRUE CACHE INTERNAL "")
    SET(CMAKE_${_prefix}_COMPILER_FORCED TRUE CACHE INTERNAL "")
    SET(CMAKE_${_prefix}_COMPILER_ID_RUN TRUE CACHE INTERNAL "")
endforeach()

set(CMAKE_AR "${AURIX_SDK_ROOT}/bin/artc")
set(CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER  "${AURIX_SDK_ROOT}/bin/astc")
set(CMAKE_LINKER  "${AURIX_SDK_ROOT}/bin/ltc")

# Search paths for libraries
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH ${AURIX_SDK_ROOT})
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)
```

Is there any way to configure CMake (version 3.16) to not use `-c` option? I did specify `CMAKE_CCOMPILER_ID` as "Tasking".

Versions:

- CMake >3.16
- TASKING VX-toolset for TriCore v6.3r1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Tasking compiler really isn't supposed to have `-c` to specify the file to compile (I wouldn't know, because I don't know that compiler), then you might be able to do this by modifying your CMake installation's `Modules/Compiler/Tasking-CXX.cmake` file to make it override the default value of `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILE_OBJECT` which gets set in the `Modules/CMakeCXXInformation.cmake` file like:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILE_OBJECT
  "<CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER> <DEFINES> <INCLUDES> <FLAGS> -o <OBJECT> -c <SOURCE>")
```

and just put that same line in the `Modules/Compiler/Tasking-CXX.cmake` except removing the `-c` argument. Or you could try putting this in your toolchain file.

At least- that's how things look to be set up to work in the CMake modules. Just grep the modules for `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILE_OBJECT` and you'll see similar overrides for specific compilers or platforms.

Disclaimer: I'm not 100% sure this will work. I just grepped the code to find something that looks like it might be the thing to poke with a stick. Documentation for `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILE_OBJECT` can be found [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_COMPILE_OBJECT.html).

The places in the CMake source code where `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILE_OBJECT` is used is in `Source/cmMakefileTargetGenerator.cxx` and `Source/cmNinjaTargetGenerator.cxx` (search for regex `CMAKE_.*_COMPILE_OBJECT`). It's pretty interesting (or very boring)- you can read how the compile command gets built by the CMake executable for various generators.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem, turned out, is the CMake version 3.25. The support for Tasking compiler was added in this version. The toolchain file looks like this:

```
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "${AURIX_SDK_ROOT}/bin/cctc" CACHE INTERNAL "")

foreach (_prefix C)
    # set(CMAKE_${_prefix}_COMPILER "${AURIX_SDK_ROOT}/bin/cctc")
    # This is used only if we skip auto compiler identification
    set(CMAKE_${_prefix}_COMPILER_ID "Tasking")
    set(CMAKE_${_prefix}_COMPILER_VERSION "Tricore")
    set(CMAKE_${_prefix}_COMPILER_ARCHITECTURE_ID "Tricore")

    # Skip compiler ID identification: use "Tasking"
    set(CMAKE_${_prefix}_COMPILER_ID_RUN TRUE CACHE INTERNAL "")
    set(CMAKE_${_prefix}_COMPILER_FORCED TRUE CACHE INTERNAL "")

    SET(CMAKE_${_prefix}_COMPILER_WORKS TRUE CACHE INTERNAL "")
    SET(CMAKE_${_prefix}_COMPILER_FORCED TRUE CACHE INTERNAL "")
    SET(CMAKE_${_prefix}_COMPILER_ID_RUN TRUE CACHE INTERNAL "")
endforeach()

set(CMAKE_AR "${AURIX_SDK_ROOT}/bin/artc")
set(CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER "${AURIX_SDK_ROOT}/bin/astc")
set(CMAKE_LINKER "${AURIX_SDK_ROOT}/bin/ltc")

# Search paths for libraries
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH ${AURIX_SDK_ROOT})
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)
```

Some notes:

1. The compiler setup emphatically *does not* support C++. Not sure why. There is a C++ compiler `cptc`.
2. The control application `cctc` should be used instead of the `ctc` compiler directly.